# How do I select mutliple lines using only the keyboard in a JetBrains IDE?

Tags: ide, keyboard-shortcuts, jetbrains-ide

A very minor annoyance of mine as this is something I need to do regularly, therefore it could speed me up considerably over time.  Say I have the following four lines:

```
File.join(root,
      'setup',
      'pre-suite',
      'install.py'),
```

If my cursor was resting before 'File' I can use CMD+SHIFT+Right arrow to highlight part of the line or the full thing, I can even move this line down the list by using the down arrow instead of the right arrow.  However, I want to select all four lines using the keyboard only, is this possible?  If so how?

Comment: Well .. don't know about Mac (based on `Cmd` in your shortcuts it's your OS) .. but on Windows `Shift+Up/Down` expands selection to include the line above/below. If unsure -- `Settings/Preferences | Keymap` and look what shortcut you have for `Editor Actions | Up/Down with Selection` actions.

Comment: Another idea - use `Edit | Extend Selection` few times in a row (how many -- depends on context). Try it.

Comment: @LazyOne you're spot on mate, thank you!  Do you want to provide that as an actual answer and I'll accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here on Windows <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Up/Down</kbd> expands selection to include the line above/below.

Since you are on Mac (based on `Cmd` in your shortcuts) ... just use `Preferences | Keymap` and look what shortcut you have got there for `Editor Actions | Up/Down with Selection` actions.

Another idea - use `Edit | Extend Selection` few times in a row (how many -- depends on context and caret position). Try it -- it does wonders; especially useful when invoked in the middle of such code block/statement.